# add tab in a tabwidget on runtime

Tags: android

I have a data base in which multiple items are there.And also I have tab widget in which tow tabs are available now i want to add a tab of the name containing some items from database on the click of any one tab from the tab widget.
Suppose i have tab1 andtab2 and in the database one item is there having name say tab3 now when i click on the tab2 ,i want to add tab3 in the tabwidget..
plz help me.....

Comment: What do you have already? Where did you really stuck? On reading the database? Creating the tabhost? Could you post some code to show us what you have and where you are stuck... And: please accept some answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a tab at any time using the same `newTabSpec()`/`addTab()` logic you are using for the initial tabs. You will need to use a `TabContentFactory`, though. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/DynamicTab) demonstrating this.